# Printing an image php

Tags: php, html

I want to print an image in a php file using the  tag, the absolute path of the said image is stocked in myphp data base as follows C:\xampp\htdocs\project\Attempt\assets\img\img.jpg.
I tried the following method but to no avail.

```
$pdo =new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login","root","");
        $stm = $pdo->prepare("select * from category");
        $stm -> execute();
        $tab = $stm->fetchAll();
        foreach($tab as $p)
        {
            echo $p["CATEGORY_ID"].'<br>';
            echo $p["NAME"].'<br>';
            echo '<img src='.$p["IMAGE"].'></img><br>';
            echo $p["COVER"].'<br>';
            echo $p["DESCRIPTION"];
        };
```

thanks

Comment: That’s a file system path specific to one computer. You need to translate that into a HTTP based path.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please either post and accept an answer, or delete this if you feel it isn’t helpful for future readers.